# Understanding the syntax of dictionaries used for graph construction and how to manipulate them

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, spanning-tree

I have the following python dictionary representing a weighted graph

```
graph1 = {
    0: {1: 1, 2: 2},
    1: {0: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 3},
    2: {0: 2, 1: 0, 5: 4},
    3: {1: 0, 4: 0},
    4: {1: 3, 3: 0, 5: 0},
    5: {2: 4, 4: 0, 6: 0},
    6: {5: 0},
}
```

I am trying to create an algorithem that allows for the generation of these graphs given number of nodes and edges. To understand how to create a graph from scratch I began by trying to add a single node to the graph above. I did the following:

```
graph1[7]={6:7}
```

This worked fine. Yet I failed to understand what the **{6:7}**  is. Is it a dictionary within the dictionary? Is it a set ?

My aim is to be able to add random edges between a set of n nodes, so Im trying to figure out how to do the following.

```
graphSize=n
for i in range(graphSize)
    for j in range(rand(graphSize))
        Graph[i].add({"node that is not i","random wieght"})
```

This however is not possible cause dictionaries dont have an append or add function. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> This worked fine. Yet I failed to understand what the {6:7} is. Is it a dictionary within the dictionary?

Yes. The syntax of dict literals in Python is `{[key: value,]*}`.

A set literal would not have the `:` (which separates keys and values).

> This however is not possible cause dictionaries dont have an append or add function. Is there another way to do this?

The same way you add items to the `Graph` dict? Just assign to the index:

```
Graph[i][j] = whatever
```